# How do I get a custom Spring 2 Authentication Provider to accept a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?

Tags: authentication, spring2.x

In Spring 2, I've created a custom authentication provider, because I can't grab the password out of the database like Spring seems to prefer, because there's a black box in the way. When I try to authenticate, I get:

> No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

I've put this bean in my security.xml:

```
<bean id="imsAuthProvider" class="com.terrapages.mokbeecds.ims.IMSAuthenticationProvider">
    <security:custom-authentication-provider />
</bean>
```

Which is, I believe, all I need. It should just grab the username and password from the form and pass it to my provider to deal with as it sees fit.
I also have this in my customAuthenticationProvider:

```
public boolean supports(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class authentication) {
    return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
}
```

Which, as I understand it, is checked before giving the authentication token to the custom authentication provider. If it returns false, then Spring checks the next authentication provider.

The main `authenticate(Authentication)` method can only throw a `BadCredentialsException` or an `AuthenticationServiceException`, which, as I understand, should not cause the output above.

Information on Spring 2 is a little hard to find, with Spring 3 being everywhere at the moment.

How do I get my provider to accept the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`?

Comment: So, I should have learnt by now that, if something seems impossible, then it means something is wrong somewhere else. I found the solution, but now I know the question is wrong, and not useful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security 2 is also documented pretty well: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/springsecurity.html
Please use the following support method:

```
public boolean supports(Class authentication) {
    return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
}
```

**Edited**

Suggestions:

1. Remove your provider - the authentication should work. If not - fix the issue.
2. Debug the authentication and supports method and see what is the problem

Comment: I have been reading that, and I don't actually agree. It's been extremely hard to find what I want. Most of my successes have come from elsewhere. Also, that code you posted is _exactly_ what I have, minus the `SuppressWarnings`. Did you actually read the question?

Comment: Yes :). Remove SuppressWarnings. I have created couple of providers in my life :)

Comment: As I thought, removing the annotation made no difference, because the annotation doesn't affect the code's behaviour once built.